# A predicated version of std::for_each

Tags: c++, template, generics, stl

For reasons, I want to implement a predicated version of `std::for_each`. I know that, in C++20, this is made somewhat redundant or less useful, as we can use `std::ranges:views::filter`; and that a more robust implementation than the one I present below might use conditional iterators (like Boost has), but - suppose I want to limit the amount of code and just get what I need, which is this templated function.

So, here it is:

```
template< typename InputIterator, typename Predicate, typename UnaryFunction >
constexpr UnaryFunction 
for_each_if(
    InputIterator  first,
    InputIterator  last,
    Predicate      p,
    UnaryFunction  f )
{
    std::for_each(first, last,
        [&](auto&& x) {
            using x_type = decltype(x);
            if (p(std::forward<x_type>(x))) {
                f(std::forward<x_type>(x));
            }
        }
    );
    return f;
}
```

You can [try it out on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fWKjMcasb). I also have an alternative version without using `std::for_each`:

```
template< typename InputIterator, typename Predicate, typename UnaryFunction >
constexpr UnaryFunction 
for_each_if(
    InputIterator  first,
    InputIterator  last,
    Predicate      p,
    UnaryFunction  f )
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        auto&& x { *first };
        using x_type = decltype(x);
        if (p(std::forward<x_type>(x))) {
            f(std::forward<x_type>(x));
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

Some specific questions:

- Which version is preferable? The latter has less dependencies, but the former has no raw loops...
- Is the `auto&&` and the forwarding overkill?
- Should I bother with a `noexcept()` clause? libc++ and libstdc++ don't seem to.
- Should I make some static assertions to give nicer error messages? Especially in the second versions?

of course, any criticism/ideas/notes are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

## Answers to your questions

> Which version is preferable? The latter has less dependencies, but the former has no raw loops...

If having less dependencies matters, then go for the raw loops. If not, then I don't think it matters much; the lambda in the first version makes it just as verbose as the second version, and they should be functionally identical.

> Is the `auto&&` and the forwarding overkill?

Yes. You normally use `std::forward` if you are forwarding a function parameter to another function. However, here we just have an iterator that we dereference. That should normally return a plain reference, so forwarding is not going to do anything useful here.

> Should I bother with a `noexcept()` clause? libc++ and libstdc++ don't seem to.

You could but then you'd have to specify an expression that is true only if both predicates and the iterator operations are `noexcept` themselves. That's a lot of work. Consider that this is a template, so the compiler will be able to inline it completely, and deduce whether any of it will throw itself.

> Should I make some static assertions to give nicer error messages? Especially in the second versions?

Yes, you could do that to make incorrect use a bit easier to debug. Even better would be to use C++20 concepts to ensure the types are all correct. It would even help in the first version, since if the error occurs inside the lambda, the error message of the compiler would probably be hard to understand as well.

## Consider creating an `apply_if()` instead

It looks straightforward and fine to me, apart from the unnecessary use of `std::forward`. However, a different approach would be to create a template function that just returns the lambda you have in the first version. You could call it `apply_if()`:

```
template<typename Predicate, typename UnaryFunction>
auto apply_if(Predicate p, UnaryFunction f) {
    return [p, f](auto& x) {
        if (p(x)) {
            f(x);
        };
    };
}
```

This way, you can compose predication with other algorithms. For example, you could then write:

```
std::for_each(first, last, apply_if(p, f));
```

Of course, the above `apply_if()` itself is not very generic and should probably be improved to handle arbitrary arguments and forward arguments in case it is used outside of another algorithm.

Comment: About the forwarding - don't I need std::forward for forwarding the kind-of-reference and the constness?

Comment: Constness is handled correctly by `auto&` itself. As for the kind-of-reference: think about what the kind-of-reference a dereferenced iterator is.

Comment: "think about what the kind-of-reference a dereferenced iterator is" <- How sure can I really be that it's an lvalue reference? Is that officially required?

Comment: Your `apply_if()` doesn't work for `for_each_if()`, because `for_each()` has a stateful `f()` and returns it. You'd need an `apply_if()` which also has this behavior.

Comment: +1: I was about to suggest the functional approach to compose the predicate and operator, and found I'd been beaten to it!

Comment: @einpoklum True. Then it should be a `class` that stores the predicate and function, has an `operator()`, and some member functions to get back the predicate and function.

Comment: @G.Sliepen: Yes, but then - do we really want to expose such a thing for general use? It's rather ugly. Of course, `for_each` itself has some of this ugliness built in to its semantics; I rather dislike how it involves this sort of stateful accumulation.

Comment: @einpoklum Well if you want `for_each_if` to act like `for_each` as much as possible, you'd have to implement this ugliness as well. Alternatively, consider having `for_each_if` and/'or `apply_if` take the predicate and function by reference.